# How to reference third party library's attrs in styles.xml?

Tags: android, android-styles

I'm using [Material Range Bar library](https://github.com/oli107/material-range-bar) which has its own [attrs](https://github.com/oli107/material-range-bar/blob/master/materialrangebar/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml) here:

```
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="RangeBar">
        <attr name="mrb_rangeBarColor" format="reference|color" />
...
```

My styles.xml:

```
  <style name="MyAppRangeBar">
    <item name="mrb_rangeBarColor">@color/gray</item>
...
```

`./gradlew assembleRelease` is giving me:

```
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > 1 exception was raised by workers:
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
     /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TestEveryPR/MyApp/cmb-views/build/intermediates/packaged_res/release/values/values.xml:884:5-893:11: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/mrb_rangeBarColor (aka com.myapppackage.prompts:attr/mrb_rangeBarColor)' not found.
```

What am I missing?

It worked in the past when our styles.xml were in the `:app` module.
Now it stopped working as I moved the styles.xml file into a `:design-library` that `:app` depends on

Comment: Does your `design-library` module specify the Material Range Bar library as one of its dependencies?

Comment: Thank you @BenP. that's the issue. Such a stupid mistake of mine :face_palm . Do you want to answer the question or the question to be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your library module (`design-library`) specifies the Material Range Bar library as one of its dependencies. Without this dependency, it won't be able to "see" the attribute, even if your `app` module includes the dependency.